# How to POST request with raw param with JSON Data Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, postman

I am trying to call API that param is accept Raw value as JSON formate. I am searching but can't get satisfied ans.

[image: Reference Image]
Any one can help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how about setting a url to the service you are calling?

Comment: @Kubee that is private so i am just remove it.

Comment: in that case it's hard to know what your problem is.  Are you having trouble with using postman?

Comment: @Kubee i get solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am try this code and working fine for me.

```
 let url = "Your URL"

        let JsonString = "Yout JSON Data" //  Ex.:-  "{\"action\": \"fetch-data\"}"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let pjson = JsonString
        let data = (pjson.data(using: .utf8))! as Data

        request.httpBody = data

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in

            print(response)

        }
```